# create a content/configuration database using local account with powershell

Tags: powershell, farm-setup, standalone, development-enviroment

so someone set up a sharepoint dev environment for me using SP2010 on Windows 2008 R2, and SQL 2008 R2, but they didn't install it as a stand alone which is what I was going after. There is no domain or active directory and I am really just looking for a stand alone to get the web app going so I can create some web part solutions and a lot of custom pages using COM.

do i need to uninstall everything (which is a lot, and redo this piece by piece) or is there a powershell method to at least get the content and config databases installed using local account (they are current not there...so upon opening the configuration wizard it cannot find any existing databases, and I get the non domain error trying to add a new farm...thought I would give it a shot). I have seen things here and there in searches but I am not greatly familiar with PS anyway/context.

all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: update: looked for this type of solution else where with no luck, just ended up re-build the server and installing all software again. probably the best approach anyway i guess.